# Google chrome for windows suddenly become very quiet

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio

Okay, so I know some of you might have this problem. I had it too, and it was really annoying. I  couldn't hear clearly even when I turn my volume to 100%. I'm here to answer my question, though, because I finally figured out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So... the solution is, go to sound settings in windows settings.

1. Under "Advanced sound options," there's "App volume and device preferences."
2. The app volume for Google Chrome was grayed out and set to 94, but when I changed the output from "Default" to "Speakers," it turned out that the volume was actually set to 1.
3. So yeah, just drag it back to 100!